# How to fix "Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function" thrown by useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks, use-effect

I have an issue with useEffect hook. In the following code the first effect fires a redux action that initializes firebase and if there is a user logged in it puts its data in the redux store. That fires an update in the component and the second effect tries to rerun and I get the console log but also the "callback is not a function" error. After that the initFinished property is set to true so the effect fires again and this time I get just the error.

[logs](https://imgur.com/a/dKiUlDw)

```js
init effect
navigate out effect false empty
render false WOMCMplIduMFRtRM2VssaMgJ2sL2
Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function
navigate out effect false WOMCMplIduMFRtRM2VssaMgJ2sL2
render true WOMCMplIduMFRtRM2VssaMgJ2sL2
Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function
```

I tried adding/removing deps from the dependency array of the effect. And I always get the same behaviour. The behaviour stays the same even if the only code in the effect is console.log. The effect runs the first time and give out a error the second time.

The component code

```
import React, { useEffect, useMemo } from 'react'
import { Text, View } from 'react-native'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Services } from '../../../reduxActions'

const AuthLoading = ({ init, authUserId, initFinished, navigation }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('init effect')
    init()
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('navigate out effect', initFinished, authUserId || 'empty')
    if (initFinished) {
      if (authUserId) {
        navigation.navigate('App')
      } else {
        navigation.navigate('Auth')
      }
    }
  }, [authUserId, initFinished])

  console.log('render', initFinished, authUserId || 'empty')
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
      }}
    >
      <Text>{authUserId || 'Loading...'}</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

export default connect(
  ({ services }) => {
    return {
      authUserId:
        services.authUser && services.authUser.uid ? services.authUser.uid : '',
      initFinished: services.initFinished
    }
  },
  dispatch => {
    return {
      init: () => {
        dispatch(Services.Actions.init())
      }
    }
  }
)(AuthLoading)
```

Dependencies:

```js
 "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.4.0",
    "firebase": "^5.11.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "rambda": "^2.5.0",
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-native": "^0.59.6",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.3.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "react-navigation": "^3.9.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.0.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "styled-components": "^4.2.0"
  },
```

Comment: could you provide the code for scheduler which is where the error originates from